# Find a row with specific text and delete this and the rest 4 rows below it

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete a specific cell area in 1000 files.

The location of this cell area is not the same in every file. In some, it starts from the A12 and in some others it starts from the A20, A21 etc.

There are 5 lines (rows) in just one column and I want to delete them all.

So, I need to :

01) find the cell (first row) with the specific text ("VVVV").

02) choose this cell and the rest 4 (below)

03) delete , select SHIFT CELLS UP

At first, I could only make it select the first row and delete it (shells shift up as well). Here is my code that now deletes the other rows but there is an issue:

```
Sub deleteRows()
'
' deleteRows Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
Dim StartRange As String
Dim EndRange As String
Cells.Find(What:="VVVV").Select
StartRange = ActiveCell.Address
EndRange = ActiveCell.Address & 4
ActiveSheet.Range(StartRange & ":" & EndRange).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

It deletes more rows than expected. That means that there is an issue with the "EndRange" value. Maybe, I will have to try to find a function that selects the range and deletes it. For example if the cell is in "A1:B1", I want to select the "A1:B1" to "A5:B5".

Comment: Will it always be a total of 5 rows to delete that are always together somewhere in the list?

Comment: @Mitch Yes. If it changes, I can change the code on my own. I ll change the number. Unless, I make it ask for an integer. But I cannot figure out how that will work with MACROS. Is there going to be a popped up window asking me to put a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    Sub deleteRows()
'
' deleteRows Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
Dim StartRange As String
Dim EndRange As String
Cells.Find(What:="VVVV").Select
StartRange = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.Offset(4, 0).Select
EndRange = ActiveCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Range(StartRange & ":" & EndRange).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: That works ! How is Selection.Offset work? You have the number 4 and 0. that means that it selects the 4 rows below and 0 columns on the right side?

Comment: The syntax is Offset(RowOffset,ColumnOffset).  Selection.Offset(4, 0).Select says to move the cursor down 4 rows and over 0 columns.  If you wanted to move up rows you can use a negative input.  Selection.Offset(-1, 1) would move the cursor up one row and right one column.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I found it. I firstly thought that it would not get negative attributes. I have been looking for this command for 3 hours. Google is not always helpful :P

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a single line of code:

```
Cells.Find(What:="VVVV").Offset(-4, 0).Resize(5, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```